# How to enable folding and 256 color support for vim/vi with Ubuntu 12-04

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vi, folding

I just turned up a new Ubuntu 12-04 instance in Rackspace, and I cannot seem to enable folding and 256 color support for vim/vi.

I want to enable folding so that indents are automatically folded (e.g. classes, functions, etc.)   When I attempt to fold, using zc, the response is "E490: No fold found".

I have tried a LOT of things, and currently have the following packages installed:

vim
vim-addon-manager
vim-athena
vim-common
vim-dbg
vim-doc
vim-gnome
vim-gtk
vim-gui-common
vim-latexsuite
vim-lesstif
vim-nox
vim-runtime
vim-scripts
vim-tiny

For the 256 color support, I have tried the following in /etc/vim/vimrc.local and in ~/.vimrc:

set t_Co=256

which does not seem to help.  Any ideas?

I am using iTerm 1.0.0.20120203 on Mac OS X, and Terminal on Ubuntu desktop, and they display folding and 256 colors on all my other servers fine.  I tried copying across a .vimrc file from an older Ubuntu install that worked, and it did not make any difference.  Once changes are made, does anything need to be restarted, or is simply opening a file with vi sufficient?

Comment: have you tried to put the setting `set t_Co=256` in `~/.vimrc` (you have to create the file yourself). for folding `set foldenable` should help you - in general you will find help most often by typing `:help sthg` in vim command-line mode to get help about sthg.

Comment: where exactly does one enter set foldenable?  is it in /etc/vim/vimrc?

Comment: you never want to enter settings in a global file - you have `~/.vimrc` to put that into; everytime you do a full setup you can copy your local files to the new setup and additionally if you have more than one user, everyone has to like your settings (highly improbable).

Answer (score 0):

Is your terminal type a terminal type that purports to support colors, such as xterm-color?

You can find out by doing:

```
$ echo $TERM
```

And if it isn't one that supports color you could do:

```
$ export TERM=xterm-color
```

I believe vim will ignore color settings if it doesn't think your terminal is capable of using them.